# Can i recreate an SSL certificate key file after loosing original one

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I had a key file on my server, but accidentally i've deleted it. Now i don't want to wait for another ssl key, is it possible to recreate a ssl certificate key for a certificate that i know every option on same server?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/17759/2435).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the normal case , no. that is the whole point of the secret key. backups..